# Почему результат не выводится в консоль?

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
  methods: {
    async google_login() {
    // Выполняем аутентификацию с Google
    await this.$auth.loginWith('google', { params: { prompt: 'select_account' } });
    // После успешной аутентификации получаем информацию о пользователе
    const response = await this.$axios.get('https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo', {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${this.$auth.strategy.token.get().accessToken}`
      }
    });

    console.log('Информация о пользователе:', response.data);
}}
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова? Или хотя бы дождаться их окончания](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%98%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b6)

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, чисто технически для получения данных все правильно написано. То есть уже используется все что в дубликате указано.

Comment: Что значит не выводится результат в консоль? Вообще ничего не выводится? Выводится ошибка? Пустое `response.data`? Нужно проверить что вообще приходит в `response`

Comment: А что выводится? Метод-то вообще вызывается? Может происходит ошибка (и это должно быть видно в консоли)?